# Does it make any sense study the finite difference operator and sum operator using functional analysis framework?

Tags: functional-analysis, finite-differences

I was wandering if it does make any sense study "difference operator" and "sum operator" using the framework of functional analysis.

As example (i just made it up)

$$\left( a_k\Delta^2 + b_k \Delta + c_k \right)u_k = \nu_k \;\; \forall k \geq 0$$
where $a_k, b_k, c_k$ and $\nu_k$ are fixed sequences.

Likewise an equation like

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}k_{m,n}u_n = x_m$$

and so on...

I have a lot of material the speaks about differential operator but much stuff about difference equations, except some book about "difference calculus" but it doesn't sounds like what i mean in such question...

Comment: Sure. For example: One may consider even a finite 'system'. Then one may exploit that projections are trivially compact and so invoke Riemann-Lebesgue so argue the existence of wave operators. See: [Paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.1480.pdf#page=55)

Comment: Could you point out some reference on this topic? a book would be nice, but even a paper or technical report would be fine too.

Comment: Already down. ;)

Comment: Hi again, do you have other reference on topic? more "math" (i mean more abstract and less physic oriented)?

Comment: Will think about it next week. *(Can you remind me then?)*

Comment: Yep, why not!!!

Comment: Alright then just ping me. :)

Comment: PING PING PING!!!!

Comment: I tried to find some reference but there's not to much in literature at least afaik. I had the same problem when I studied the discrete Laplacian. But what you might keep in mind is that in principle you can apply all functional analytic results. The point is that the square summable spaces are not only specific examples for Hilbert spaces but also the canonical ones. ...

Comment: ... That is *any* Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is isomorphic to some square summable space $\ell^2(S)$ over an index set $S$ with cardinality equal the dimension $\#S=\dim\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: But I agree with that it would be nice to have some literature on discrete Laplacians that investigates its spectral properties. *(I missed that during my thesis too.)*

Comment: I can understand the isomorphism between an hilbert space and $\ell{l}^2 (S)$ however this would mean that if i have a discrete problem i should somehow map such problem into a continous space, isn't? then go back into the discrete space (i hope i'm clear enough) it sound a little twisted as procedure.

Comment: You can do that and in fact that is what is done in the paper above. That might be helpful but in my opinion this is contraproductive as you are already given its own canonical space so it wouldn't make sense to construct another Hilbert space out of it. But maybe you can find out why they do so anyway. I guess it is to obtain a multiplication version of the selfadjoint discrete Laplacian.

Comment: I guess i have to be happy with the paper you pointed out... even if sound's a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Yeah the paper is rather physical. _*sad*_ *(Let me know if you find something else)*

Comment: In any case for your question from me: (+1)